# AngularJS - link to an anchor link on a different page

Tags: html, angularjs, anchor

I'm wondering if someone could advise me... I am not very familiar with AngularJS but I am currently working on a site that uses it. I have several scenarios where I have to link to an anchor link on a different page/different url and if I was to simply put it as this for example:

```html
<a href="www.website-address.com#anchorlink">Click here to view this link</a>
```

It causes a 404. I have found several solutions for anchor links within the same page but nothing that works with AngularJS to link to an anchor link on a different page/url.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: try like this `<a href="http://www.website-address.com#anchorlink">Click here to view this link</a>`. Your code takes to the url from the app root.

Comment: Add a slash to separate the domain name and path: `http://www.website-address.com/#anchorlink`

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs parses href's for redirection. It attempts to go to a view with `anchorlink`

Try setting this in your routes

// use the HTML5 History API
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

And om your html header, set a base location of your site with `<base href="/">`

This should make angularjs stop interfering with anchor tags in your urls.

**EDIT**

@Sabarish Senthilnathan's comment works also, probably the best way too.